# How to delete/debug multiple rows with Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a `Foos` entity associated to `foos` table.
I'm trying to delete many rows from there using `createQueryBuilder()`.

I am failing with that task, and nothing is logged, no exception, and no DELETE queries sent to mysql (I tried to log all queries in mysql).

Am I missing something?

```php
/** @var  Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface $this->entityManager */
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->delete('Foos', 'foo')
    ->where('foo.some_column = :someAttr and another_column != :anotherAttr')
    ->setParameter('someAttr', $someAttr)
    ->setParameter('anotherAttr', $anotherAttr);
```

I inspected the `getDQL()` and the parts and query seems to be correct. But the test rows are not being deleted as expected.

How can I debug or make it right?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yivi. Thank you very much.
In fact it was a basic thing. I didn't notice that I was just missing the most important part. :)
In the end I did a prepared statement with something like 

`$stmt = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($deleteSql);
$stmt->execute(['someColumn' => $valueSomeColumn, 'otherColumn'=>$otherValue]);`
But I tested your approach too, and it works. :)

Comment: @yivi remember you don't need/should not downvote people just because they delayed some reply. That's not nice. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing the query.

`$qb`, in your example, is just a `QueryBuilder`, as evidenced by the call to `createQueryBuilder()`.

After you are done building the query, you need to get the built object and execute it:

```
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```